# Performing a complex multi-table search query with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am making, as a personal project - just for fun, and for learning purposes - a PHP and MySQL dictionary. I have come up against a problem, however, when I tried to be more precise about how MySQL retrieves a dictionary entry.

The intention of my query is to search for the supplied word as a 'word' in the 'entries' table (described further down), and, if a result is found, list every 'alternative' from 'alternatives' with it.

But, if no result is found, the query is to then search 'alternatives', searching for the supplied word as the 'alternative', and then return the corresponding result from the 'entries' table with the same 'word'.

I was able to achieve this with this sloppy code:

```
SELECT alternatives.word, alternatives.alternative, entries.added
  FROM alternatives
 INNER JOIN entries
    ON entries.word = alternatives.word
 WHERE entries.word = (SELECT word
                         FROM alternatives
                        WHERE alternative = "randomword"
                           OR word = "randomword" LIMIT 1)
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't take into account a key problem with this, which is that a word can be in 'alternatives', but still have an entry in 'entries'. (for example, 'entries' might contain 'query' and 'querying', and 'query' will see 'querying' as an alternative, while 'querying' will see 'query' as an alternative.)

The 'alternatives' table:

```
id | word [the word the alternative word is based on] | alternative [alternative word] | type [verb/noun/adjective etc...]
```

The 'entries' table:

```
id | word [the word] | date [timestamp of entry, must be returned]
```

Is there an easy solution to this problem? I am completely stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on exactly what you're after but if I'm understanding correctly and if this code does what I think it does then it could work.

From what I understand you want to look up the word in entries and if it exists you want to return it with its creation date and in the same result set you also want to return every word and its date which appears as an alternative for that word.
If it's not found then you want to return from the alternatives table every other word for which the searched for word is an alternative and its timestamp

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM entries WHERE word = 'wordtosearch') THEN
BEGIN
    SELECT a.alternative, e.date 
    FROM alternatives a 
        INNER JOIN entries e ON a.alternative = e.word 
    WHERE a.word = 'wordtosearch'
    UNION
    SELECT word, date
    FROM entries
    WHERE word = 'wordtosearch';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT e.word, e.date 
    FROM alternatives a 
        INNER JOIN entries e ON a.word = e.word 
    WHERE a.alternative = 'wordtosearch';
END;
END IF;
```

One thing to be wary of here is that you want completely different logic based on the existence of a record, this may be possible with joins but I thought the easiest and most readable solution would be split the two operations entirely.
Also it is important that both result sets return the same columns otherwise you could end up with an unknown result set definition (i.e. unknown numbers of columns) which is difficult to handle properly.

Comment: I tried to run this, but it's giving me an error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM entries WHERE word = "wordtosearch") BEGIN SELECT' at line 1`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm used to working with SQL server and the MYSQL syntax is slightly different. I have edited my answer.